# Magento 2 - Use \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Widget\Chooser with multiple selections?

Tags: magento2, catalog, widget, magento-2.0.4, product-chooser

Using this code

```
$chooser = $this->_layout->createBlock('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Widget\Chooser');
        var_dump(get_class_methods($chooser));

        $configChooser = [
            'button' => [
                'open' => __('Select Products'),
                'type' => '\Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Widget\Chooser',
            ]
        ];
        $chooser->setConfig($configChooser)
            ->setFieldsetId($fieldsetData->getId())
        ->prepareElementHtml($productChooser);
```

I can get a pretty nice product selector for my custom field in my custom form, but i need it to be able to select several product. **There is a chooser config that i can be able to set?**

Comment: Hi Gianni, can you share more code for Product Chooser  in custom module form, please. I want to figured out that but I couldn't. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <fieldset name="assign_products" sortOrder="40">
            <settings>
                <collapsible>true</collapsible>
            <label translate="true">Products</label>
            </settings>
                <container name="assign_products_container" sortOrder="160">
                 <htmlContent name="html_content">
                     <block name="my_assigned_products" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Grid">
                     <arguments>
                            <argument name="button" xsi:type="array">
                             <item name="open" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Select Product...</item>
                            </argument>
                     </arguments>
                     </block>
            </htmlContent>
            </container>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: perfact work on my custom ui form thanks a lot.

Comment: I got 
main.CRITICAL: Invalid method Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Grid::prepareElementHtml

Answer (score 0):

```
<fieldset name="assign_products" sortOrder="40">
```

true
Products






Select Product...

---

use **Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Grid** instead of Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Widget\Chooser